# Как настроить навигационную цепочку?

Tags: битрикс

у меня url строятся без вложенных разделов, но ссылки в навигационой цепочке почему с вложенными разделами, из-за чего попадаю на 404, как это исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: неправильно строятся ссылки в навигационной цепочке, то есть например в инфоблоке настроено построение url как catalog/#SECTION_CODE# и соответственно ссылки строятся без вложенных разделов, но в навигационной цепочке почему то с воженными, например /catalog/section1/section2/element

Comment: @sreug34 это не нужно объяснять боту, просто добавьте детали в вопрос, нажав на кнопку [edit]